# Click image inside a TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tableview

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to create a ProfileViewController (where the user profile is loaded, like profile image, likes and pictures) by making a click in the profile image inside a TableViewController (TableView).

At the moment is not working, because everything that I touch is going to a Segue (the post's segue where you can see the entry, likes and comments) but I need to create something (maybe it's a touch gesture) over the author image of that entry and show me his profile.

I have tried by creating a Tap Gesture Recognizer but it's not working. Also a Segue action directly in the Storyboard, and it's not working.

I'm going to show you an example, because at the ends it's like Facebook wall:

[image: Example Image]

If I touch in the profile image it displays the user profile page with his information. I want to achieve that but with the image inside a TableView.

Here is what I got at the moment:

**TableViewController.m**

```
//
//  CarTableViewController.m
//  Copyright (c) 2014. All rights reserved.
//

#import "CarTableViewController.h"
#import "CarTableViewCell.h"
#import "CarTableViewController.h"
#import "CarDetailViewController.h"
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>

@implementation CarTableViewController

@synthesize carMakes = _carMakes;
@synthesize carModels = _carModels;
@synthesize carImages = _carImages;

@synthesize likes = _likes;
@synthesize comments = _comments;
@synthesize username = _username;
@synthesize refuser = _refuser;
@synthesize profileImage = _profileImage;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self fetchJson];

    [self.tableView reloadData];

    // Initialize the refresh control.
    self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    //self.refreshControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    //self.refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.refreshControl addTarget:self
                            action:@selector(fetchJson)
                  forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [_jsonArray count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"carTableCell";

    CarTableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                              dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CarTableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.makeLabel.text = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"id"];
    cell.likes.text = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"likes"];
    cell.comments.text = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"comments"];
    cell.username.text = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"username"];
    cell.refuser.text = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"user_ref"];

    cell.modelLabel.text = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"user"];

    NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"imagen"]];

    [cell.carImage setImageWithURL:imageURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imagen"] options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];

    NSURL * imageURL2 = [NSURL URLWithString:[[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"image"]];

    [cell.profileImage setImageWithURL:imageURL2
                      placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"]
                            options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];

    return cell;
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowCarDetails"])
    {
        CarDetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

        NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        detailViewController.carDetailModel = [[NSArray alloc]
                                               initWithObjects:
                                               [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:[myIndexPath row]] valueForKey:@"date"],
                                               [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:[myIndexPath row]] valueForKey:@"id"],
                                               [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:[myIndexPath row]] valueForKey:@"imagen"],
                                               nil];
    }
}

-(void)fetchJson {

    self.carModels = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.carMakes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.carImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.likes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.comments = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        NSString * urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://website.com/service.php"];
        NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
        NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

        NSError *error;
        [_jsonArray removeAllObjects];
        _jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:data
                      options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                      error:&error];


            for(int i=0;i<_jsonArray.count;i++)
            {
                NSDictionary * jsonObject = [_jsonArray objectAtIndex:i];
                NSString* imagen = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"imagen"];
                [_carImages addObject:imagen];

                NSDictionary * jsonObject2 = [_jsonArray objectAtIndex:i];
                NSString* user = [jsonObject2 objectForKey:@"user"];
                [_carMakes addObject:user];

                NSDictionary * jsonObject3 = [_jsonArray objectAtIndex:i];
                NSString* date = [jsonObject3 objectForKey:@"date"];
                [_carModels addObject:date];
            }
         NSLog(@"carModels ==> %@", _jsonArray);

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            {
                [self.tableView reloadData];
                [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
            }});

        }
    );
}

@end
```

Regards,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I used to do this with a gesture recognizer...

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapOnCheck:)];

    tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    tapped.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    tapped.cancelsTouchesInView = YES;
    [cell.imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapped];
```

As you can see, my target action was "tapOnCheck:" and my image was cell.imageView, but you can simply adapt this code to your code...

Hope this helped!

Bye

Answer (score 0):

You can try simple solution.

Remove all segues from cell.
Then You need to override in CarTableViewCell, UIView's method which called:
 - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
In this method detect touch location. Compare it with location of image.
If touch location is in image - send message to cell's delegate(it is your controller) which says that touch in Image on Cell.
Else - send message to cell's delegate which says that touch in other location in Cell.

Then choose segue to push.

Hope this will help you.